# uninitialized constant error in Rails connecting to MySQL after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just upgraded Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 and when I try to run a project locally in Rails  2.3.14 I'm getting this error:

> uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

Is there a way of fixing this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should re-install the gem you are using to connect to the database.

For example, if you are using `mysql2` gem, then you can do:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2
```

This will re-build the native extensions that the Ubuntu upgrade messed up.

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading the gem sometimes get's messed up.
You don't need to uninstall it, just installing again is enough.

```
gem install mysql2
```

I've seen this happen with the mysql gem too.